# Simulink Convert Single to 4 Bytes

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to convert a single to 4 bytes in order to send them by serial port.
for example `30:0x41 0xF0 0x00 0x00`
I don't know if a `Simulink` block already exists or if I should create a `matlab function` for this aim.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simulink block called "Extract Bits". This can extract any set of bits from the input. Your input need to be of integer type. You would need to use 4 such blocks to get the 4 bytes.

See documentation for the block at http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/extractbits.html

For unpacking double or single data types you need "Byte Pack" block from Embedded Coder product. You can find documentation at http://www.mathworks.com/help/ecoder/ref/bytepack.html.

Comment: but I want convert a "single" not an integer. how does work to have 4 bytes, i don't understand well?

Comment: For that you need Byte Pack from embedded coder product. I updated my answer. If not you need to write it in a matlab function.